# Expert-model and machine learning hybrid approach

Tags: classification, natural-language, unbalanced-classes

Is there a recommended approach how the results of an rule-based expert system can be combined with an ML model?

Let's say you have a text classification problem with 100 classes. For some classes you have only very little training data, but pretty accurate keyword-based rules, while for other classes you have plenty of training data, but only weak rules. The obvious approach would be to combine a rule-based approach with a ML model.

As I understand Weak Supervision (e.g. SnorkelAI) only tries to speed up the labelling process, but that wouldn't help if you just don't find many examples for a certain class.

So I am wondering how can be the results of an expert-model can be combined with a ML model in an optimal way?

Comment: Why not use the standard approaches of model combination like weighted mixture of experts, ensembles, or hierarchical versions thereof? Do you think there is something special about expert models which makes those techniques less appropriate?

Comment: I did some research about mixture of experts, looks interesting, but didnt find a python library to give it a try, adding the output of the rules or the expert based prediction as additional features to a single model would be another option?